# How to generate/handle listeners on Trinket?

Tags: c, arduino, listener

Is there any way to implement a listener? On a PC machine it's easy to do - forking the process and using a global variable can tell you if your listener found something, but I don't know if this is possible to do on a trinket, or maybe there's some kind of option to handle this?

Basically, I just want to do some stuff when some pin is low (for example, joining two pins by a switch, then when switch is pulled do something).

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use **interrupts** or **pin polling**, i.e. if you connect the switch to a pin that is linked to an *external interrupt* (see the datasheet of the MCU for this), this interrupt will be triggered when the state on the pin changes i.e. from high to low. The interrupt will be handled in an [Interrupt Service Routine](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Interrupts) (ISR) then. This is similar to a listener.

Alternatively you can poll the state of the pin in specific periods. Polling means checking if state is high or low i.e. each 50 ms (possibly triggered by a timer). This is not the best solution.

- http://avrlogic.blogspot.de/2014/11/polling.html
- http://avrlogic.blogspot.de/2014/11/switch-interfacing.html

Comment: Ok, I saw some things about `attachInterrupt()` but thought it only works on Arduino (not in Trinket). About making a polling system, it was plan B for me, hehe. Thank you.

Comment: interrupts work on any microcontroller. on the trinket is an ATtiny85. for its interrupts see its datasheet http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1698186.pdf on page 47 ff. the `attachInterrupt()` is only the arduino-specific language you can use interrupts also in C or assembly

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I saw some examples, and looks like I have to get `sei()` to work! I will look further to this function, maybe then ask you something else :)